# Retrieve values from the reponse xml by GetGetElementByTheTagName

Tags: xml, perl

```
  Getting the  linkedin user profile

     my $profile_xml = $li->request(
                       request_url         => 'http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,positions,industry,distance)',
                       access_token        => $access_token->{token},
                       access_token_secret => $access_token->{secret},
```

);

I got the result  but i want to get the id, first-name, last-name separately. how to use the GetElementByTheTagName to retrieve the values.

Comment: can you print the $profile_xml value here

Comment: bYdSs9C Jack Rudloph 123456789 2001 2 true vra Systems Information Technology and Services Information Technology and Services 0
Like this printing in one line its received as a xml contents from that we have to extract the values .

Comment: If the result is an array or xml format? If it is in array $profile_xml[0], $profile_xml[1], $profile_xml[2] would print id, first and lastnames. If it is xml then you need to parse xml file to get the values.

Comment: Its not in the array format. So i have to write in the file then have to extract or is there any other way to extract.

Comment: if it is a string then you can split the string :)

Comment: But when i split and print it shows some xml element also. So only i get little confused
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <person>
    <id>bYdSs9C</id>
    <first-name>Jack</first-name>
    <last-name>Rudloph</last-name>
    </person>

This is what received and i showed how its printed in the page . How can i extract from this.

Comment: If it is xml content .. you have to parse it ..use XML::Simple, or XML::libXML modules

Comment: if you able to manage the xml content like this:                        $str = '<id>bYdSs9C</id><first-name>Jack</first-name> <last-name>Rudloph</last-name>';
we can use this to get the fields
while ($str =~ /<.*?>(.*?)<\/.*?>/g) {
        print $1, "\n";
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i am showing that how to parse the linked profile values from xml which is received in the response but not by the GetElementbyTheTagname.

```
  my $parser = XML::Parser->new( Style => 'Tree' );
  my $tree   = $parser->parse( $profile_xml );
  print Dumper( $tree );

  my $UID = $tree->[1]->[4]->[2],"\n";
  print "User ID:$UID";
  print"</br>";
```

This is the way we can parse the values from the received response.

Answer (score 0):

if you able to manage the xml content like this:

```
 $str = '<id>bYdSs9C</id><first-name>Jack</first-name> <last-name>Rudloph</last-name>';
```

we can use this to get the fields

```
while ($str =~ /<.*?>(.*?)<\/.*?>/g) {
        print $1, "\n";
}
```

Comment: can you explain the while what it will do. why am asking means its printing the same thing what i showed.

Comment: hey first make sure that the string is in the above format then only it works, the while loop looks for <tag>info</tag> format in the string and gets the value using parenthisis part :). If you want to test this one. test it on your instance with the above example. If it works plz vote it :)

Comment: i am really confused you can see the orginal source by type linkedin api cpan in google and and go to the link and search profile_xml there you can see. so you can get little more clear what i asked .